# How to reduce length for webpage in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My Login screen is looking like this and I have to make it mobile responsive.

[image]
It is a project on ROR so I have `html.erb` file for **view**:

```
<body class="app flex-row align-items-center">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-group login-margin">
        <div class="card p-4">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
            <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <%= f.text_field :email, required: false, placeholder: 'Email', class: 'form-control', type: 'text'  %>
              </div>

              <div class="input-group mb-4">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <%= f.text_field :password, required: false, placeholder: 'Password', class: 'form-control', type: 'password'  %>
              </div>

              <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <%= f.button :submit, "Login", :class => 'mt-4 btn btn-md btn-primary' %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 text-right forget-link-margin">
                  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to either reduce the length of the page so that the card automatically zooms in or make the card bigger and centered. Either way, I want it to look better on mobile.

**EDIT**
You can visit [this link](https://hr.clustox.com) to inspect the page yourself if you want.

Comment: What's interesting for us is the rendered HTML in the browser and all CSS that's relevant for this page, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: @cloned almost all the classes are bootstrap classes. Other than those are a couple which have some pixles margins..dont think they matter

Comment: you can suggest me the solution after ignoring the rendered views.

Comment: please check the edit @cloned

Comment: don't post a liink to a site, always include all relevant code here in the question. The code on your site can change, the code in your question will remain.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the bootstrap grid to divide your view:

So make it responsive you have to specify the columns for all types of devices for that use following list :

```
+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|    device    | device sizes  | column class |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| Extra_small  | [< 576px]     | : col-       |
| Small        | [≥ 576px]     | : col-sm-    |
| Medium       | [≥ 768px]     | : col-md-    |
| Large        | [≥ 992px]     | : col-lg-    |
| Extra_large  | [≥ 1200px]    | : col-xl-    |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

For more details here is [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) on a responsive grid system.
If you want full width just give mobile size class a full with `col-sm-12`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `d-flex` on `body`

```
<body class="app flex-row align-items-center d-flex">
```

Comment: didnt make any difference